# Strange C# to SQL Dynamic Query Execution

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

All, I have a dynamic SQL Query that I am executing from a C# application. The problem query is an INSERT statement, which is run from within a C# loop, being executed sequentially on many databases to create a single data warehouse [database]. I have run this code one 100+ databases in a single batch without problem; however, I have just come across one specific database where the query

```
DECLARE @DbName NVARCHAR(128);
SET @DbName = (SELECT TOP 1 [DbName] 
               FROM [IPACostAdmin]..[TmpSpecialOptions]);
DECLARE @FilterSql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @FilterSql = (SELECT TOP 1 [AdditionalSQL] 
                  FROM [IPACostAdmin]..[TmpSpecialOptions]);
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SQL1 NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SQL2 NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQL1 = 
'INSERT INTO [' + @DbName + ']..[Episode] WITH(TABLOCK) 
    ([EstabID],..., [InclFlag]) '; 
SET @SQL2 = 
'SELECT 
     [EstabID],..., [InclFlag] 
FROM [B1A] ' + @FilterSql + ';'; 
SET @SQL = @SQL1 + @SQL2;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Goes from taking roughly three seconds for an insert of 20,000-30,000 records to 40+ minutes! Now, after long deliberation and experiments, I have just worked out the fix for this; it is to use

```
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL WITH RECOMPILE;
```

This brings it back down to < 2s for the insert.

This SQL is executed from the application once for each database in the batch, the current execution of this statement *should* be totally separate from the preceding ones as far as the server is concerned (as I understand it), but it is not; it seems SQL is cashing the dynamic SQL in this case.

I would like to know what is happening here for this single site? Where will I need to ensure I use the `RECOMPILE` option in future to prevent such issues?

Thanks for your time.

_Note. I appreciate that this recompiles the query, but I am baffelled as to why the server is using the same execution plan in the first place. each time this query is run it is against a different database using a different `Initial Catalog` using a different `SqlConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

when you do RECOMPILE, sql server will generate each time new execution plan and execute it. other wise it will try to use an existing execution plan stored in the procedure cache, which may be wrong for the current query as in dynamic query, conditions and parameters get changed each time it executes..

Comment: I understand this aspect of the problem, but I don't understand how it can be using the same execution plan - I am actually using a _different_ `SqlConnection` each time this query is run (it is run against different databases)! So when using dynamic SQL when should I use the `RECOMPILE` option? Like I say, this has worked for hundreds of databases in the past with out issue, but for this one it is failing. How can I prevent such troubles in the future?